# How to generate a key in Qt using openssl?

Tags: qt, ssl, openssl

I need to create a private key using openssl in Qt and then use that key to sign a zip file? I dont even have a clue on how to do this! Can somebody help me to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating a key is a multi-step process: create a "certificate signing request" CSR, give the CSR to the "certificate authority" CA, the CA will sign the certificate and return to you a public certificate. (You do this once at first program execution.) You add the certificate and private key to your certificate store (once per program execution), and *then* you can finally sign the file (probably using an `EVP_*` function). (Once per zip file.)

Good luck :) OpenSSL is a beast. I suggest using a helper tool such as [TinyCA](http://tinyca.sm-zone.net/) if you're also going to be your own CA. (There's nothing wrong with learning the openssl command line for CA functions, it is just a ton of extra work that doesn't get you much closer to your immediate goal. Still worth looking at.)